# problema para tomar valor del select

Tags: javascript, html, select

Les escribo por problemas con un select, que aunque se que han solventado bastantes dudas con respecto a este tema, no he encontrado nada en internet que me ayudara.

```js
 function desplegar(){
    var valor = document.getElementById(desplegar);
    var texto = valor.options[valor.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(texto); 
 }
```

```html
<select id=“desplegar” onchange=desplegar()>
  <optgroup label=“a”>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label=“d”>
    <option>e</option>
    <option>f</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Esta ha sido una opción muy simple pero que muchos usan, donde se supone debería tomar lo guardado en el id "desplegar" y luego obtener el texto de la opción seleccionada he imprimirlo en forma de alert, pero la linea `var texto = valor.options[valor.selectedIndex].text;` indica lo siguiente:

> **`null is not an object (evaluating 'valor.options'`**

También he alternado entre otras opciones pero no me acepta parámetros como options, selectedIndex y otros relacionados
Les agradezco por su servicio.

Comment: Es decir debe mostrar e o f en un alert al momento de elegirlos?

Comment: Te faltó poner entre comillas ID del elemento: `var valor = document.getElementById('desplegar');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es obtener el texto del `option` seleccionado puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```js
function desplegar(){
    var valor = document.querySelector('select[id=“desplegar”] option:checked').text;
   alert(valor);
 }
```

```html
<select id=“desplegar” onchange=desplegar()>
  <optgroup label=“a”>
    <option>b</option>
    <option>c</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label=“d”>
    <option>e</option>
    <option>f</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

Con [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) y dentro del selector apuntas al select y después a la opción seleccionada solventas el problema de **null** aparte de ser mas eficiente al usar solo una variable.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la inmediatez de su respuesta, me sirvió a la perfección. honestamente no sé por qué la opción que yo publiqué no me funcionaba pero esta sirve a perfección. ¿tengo que hacer algo para cerrar este hilo como corregido o solo voto tu respuesta como correcta y dejo de responder?

Comment: @Adrián21 si consideras que la respuesta es correcta te invito a pulsar el el tic que aparece  cerca de las votaciones, así recibes algo de reputación y dejas cerrada la pregunta para que otros con el mismo problema puedan encontrar la solucion, aparte que recibiremos algo de reputación. No te funcionaba por varios motivos, el primero, en `getElementById` tienes que poner el elemento buscado como string `"desplegar"`, otro que se escapa de mi conocimiento, no te encontraba el elemento y te rellenaba la variable como null, dándote ese fallo